# CDK CLI >= 1.16.0 is required to interact with this app

Tags: python, jenkins, pip, aws-cdk

Hi I am working on AWS CDK. I am integrating it with Jenkins Pipeline. Below is my pipeline.

```
 withCredentials([[$class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding', credentialsId: "${env.PROJECT_ID}-aws-${env.ENVIRONMENT}"]]) {
            docker.image("${ECR_HOST}/sharedtools/cdk:latest").inside {
              sh "./scripts/build.sh"
            }
          }
```

I am using latest cdk image here.

Below are my commands.

```
python3 -m venv .env && \
  source .env/bin/activate && \
  pip3 install aws-cdk.cdk==0.36.1
  pip3 install aws-cdk.core

    cdk synth
```

When cdk synth is run I get below error.

```
Installing collected packages: my-setup
  Found existing installation: my-setup 0.0.1
    Uninstalling my-setup-0.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled my-setup-0.0.1
  Running setup.py develop for my-setup
Successfully installed my-setup
+ cdk synth
CDK CLI >= 1.16.0 is required to interact with this app
```

Can someone help me to fix this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I don't know anything about AWS CDK, but it looks like `pip3 install aws-cdk.cdk==0.36.1` implies that you don't have `CDK CLI >= 1.16.0`, right?

Comment: I removed that and tried and still same error. Actually aws-cdk.cdk==0.36.1 deprecated. Now aws-cdk.core is enough

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the AWS CDK as a npm module:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/getting_started.html

`npm install -g aws-cdk`

> Why does a Python, C#, or Java developer need to install Node.js? The AWS CDK and the AWS Construct Library are developed in TypeScript, then transpiled to JavaScript. The AWS CDK Toolkit (cdk command-line tool) and the bindings for other supported languages make use of the AWS CDK engine running on Node.js.